# Submit button working at times but stops working on several app usage

Tags: javascript

Thanks in advance

I am trying to get the value of an text area input field using vanila js but I don't get the updated value, that is , I have already fed in some pre-value for the tex tarea which is updated accordingly but upon posting, the only data I get is the pre-fed value.

```
document.getElementById('jjeditlab').elements.namedItem('textarea_input_{{ $item->results->id }}').value
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the value at the time your code runs.

If you want to get the value later, then run the code later.

e.g. in an event handler or `setInterval`.